# mean of absolute value of groupby object pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, absolute-value

I want to compute the mean of the absolute value of a grouped object.

I.e.

```
grouped = df.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper(3MS)])

dct['x'] = grouped['profit'].agg('mean') / grouped['cost'].abs().agg('mean')
```

However, the above code results in an error. I have tried various variants of the above code but so far all result in errors.

There must be a simple way to do this.

Update:

This is the dataframe that is grouped vi pd.TimeGrouper(3MS). I want to take the absolute value of column cost 1, and then compute the mean.

```
            cost1  cost2  cost3  cost4  
date                                                                       
2016-03-31       -490.60        -118.10         -344.87           -91.44   
2016-04-30       -188.74         -55.99         -259.23           -75.16   
2016-05-31       -158.62         -43.58         -176.37           -21.98
```

I tried to do `grouped['cost1'].abs().mean()` but I got:

```
/Users/User1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in __getattr__(self, attr)
    493             return self[attr]
    494         if hasattr(self.obj, attr):
--> 495             return self._make_wrapper(attr)
    496 
    497         raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %

/Users/User1/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _make_wrapper(self, name)
    507                    "using the 'apply' method".format(kind, name,
    508                                                      type(self).__name__))
--> 509             raise AttributeError(msg)
    510 
    511         # need to setup the selection

AttributeError: ("Cannot access callable attribute 'abs' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method", u'occurred at index 0')
```

Comment: can you post some sample data and what your error is? Otherwise we are guessing what is wrong here.

Comment: I added the information you suggested. Thank you for offering to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your update, I think you are looking for one mean taken on absolute values for the group.

Using `grouped.apply(abs).mean()` will apply the `abs` function to values in your group (`cost1` etc), and the `mean` will give you the average for whatever your grouping variable is.

You could also just apply the `abs` function before grouping, and then use the `mean` function directly.

Comment: As suggested here, you can convert all values by .abs() and then add .mean() to the end of the line you apply group by function

Answer (score 0):

You're probably getting the error because you can't use `.agg` on a Sereis object.

You didn't post your grouped object so I don't know if there are other issues but you should try it this way. I think this should work:

```
dct['x'] = grouped['profit'].mean() / grouped['cost'].abs().mean()
```

Comment: Thank you Joe for the reply. I just added further information to my post.