# Group a pandas dataframe, then take the mean of the abs by aggregation

Tags: python, pandas

I cannot figure out how to do the following:

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe with 3 columns, `A`, `B`, and `C`.

I want to first group by `A`, then do aggregation on `B` and `C`. Let's say I want to take the `mean` of `B` and the `max` of `C`, then I could simply do:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 
                   'B' :[50, 70, 50, 30] ,
                   'C' : [100, -150, -110, 180] })

df.groupby("A").agg({"B":"mean", "C":"max"})
```

What I want to do, however, is to take the `max` of the `abs` value of C.

I tried various ways, including the way described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230571/4629950), but somehow, it never gives me what I wants. I am sure there is a simple answer for this... what am I doing wrong?

The expected output would of course be

> C A
>      a  60  **150**
>      b  40  180

Answer (score 2):

I think need custom function:

```
df1 = df.groupby("A").agg({"B":"mean", "C":lambda x: x.abs().max()})
print (df1)
     C   B
A         
a  150  60
b  180  40
```

Another solution is [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) back column of [`abs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.abs.html) values:

```
df1 = df.assign(C = lambda x: x['C'].abs()).groupby("A").agg({"B":"mean", "C":"max"})
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.assign(C = lambda x: x['C'].abs()))
   A   B    C
0  a  50  100
1  a  70  150
2  b  50  110
3  b  30  180
```